# How to disable sounds on messages sent in various apps?

Tags: notifications

A lot of apps have annoying sounds on various actions that I personally don't care about. For example WhatsApp and Facebook Messenger make a sound when you send a message. I can't figure out how this sound is classified, and how to disable it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For messenger you have "in app sounds" in messenger settings, there is probably similar option in whatsapp.

Comment: Thanks! It helped. I was asking about what kind of type of sound they fall into so I can mute them in the settings, but this works for me.

Comment: Confirmed, there is no general setting but all of the chat apps I use have the settings "outgoing sound" or something similar that has to be turned off individually.